# Stored Procedure: Get month

Tags: mysql, function, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure that when given a month value, returns the user the last day of the month.

So far:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getLastDayMonth$$
CREATE PROCEDURE getLastDayMonth(IN inMonth int) 
BEGIN
    SELECT LAST_DAY(inMonth);
END $$
```

I am having trouble figuring out how i can make `inMonth` a parameter that the sql function `Last_DAY` accepts. Is there another function that takes in an int as a month and returns the last day of the month? I am trying to avoid giving a `DATE` type as a paramater

Comment: Which month in which year is inMonth supposed to stand for? This year, last year, next year...? (Not necessarily important for March to January, but for February, the year is crucial!)

Comment: inMonth is supposed to be any arbitrary month, the year isn't important as long as the last day can be returned. I understand the issue of February but whatever the Last_Day function can give for month 02 is fine

Comment: out of curiosity: what is the last day used for? As a user, I would be a bit confused, if the procedure would return me Feb 28th instead of 29th or vice versa ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add moths to first year day and get last_date:

```
SELECT LAST_DAY( DATE_ADD( '2012-01-01 00:00:00',  
                           INTERVAL inMonth - 1 MONTH) 
               );
```

Alternative solution is [ELT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-functions.html#function_elt) function:

```
SELECT cast( 
         ELT(inmonth, '31', '28', '31', '30', '31', .... ,'31' )
         as SMALLINT 
       ) as last_day
```

The last one, use `case` statement:

```
SELECT case inmonth
        when 1 then 31
        when 2 then 29
        ...
        when 12 then 31
       end as last_day
```

**EDITED**

```
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE getLastDayMonth(IN inMonth int)
    -> begin
    -> SET @t=inMonth -1;
    -> SELECT LAST_DAY( DATE_ADD( '2012-01-01 00:00:00',INTERVAL @t MONTH));
    -> end@@
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.24 sec)
```

Comment: @danihp i am trying to test your first solution and i keep getting a mysql syntax error, is the DATE_ADD function suppose to have the -1 as a variable?

Comment: i added the DAY function as Last_Day returns a date. Thanks